# Java Applet Running in Netbeans, but won't run in browser

Tags: java, applet, noclassdeffounderror

I have created a Java applet with Netbeans.  It is a GUI banner creator.  It runs fine in Netbeans applet viewer, but when I load it using HTML, I get an error.  It is finding the class file, but then I get:

```
org/jdesktop/beansbinding/Property
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.createApplet(Plugin2Manager.java:3136)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Plugin2Manager.java:1497)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/beansbinding/Property
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2389)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2699)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:326)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$13.run(Plugin2Manager.java:3060)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:199)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:638)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:636)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:647)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Property
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Applet2ClassLoader.java:252)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:249)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:179)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Plugin2ClassLoader.java:160)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 20 more
Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/beansbinding/Property
```

I have read some places that I need to right click on my project and then go to the libraries.  Once I'm there I do have Beans Binding Library installed.  Also there was somewhere else where a beans.jar file is installed (which I have).

How do I solve this run-time exception?

Comment: What is the HTML used to launch the applet?  Please edit it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdesktop/beansbinding/Property
```

Add the Jar containing the `org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Property` class to the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.